# fast forwarding Audio file using media player android

Tags: android, media-player

how to fast forwarding an Audio file using media player in android on seekbar progress change?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the ['seekTo()'-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo%28int%29) and jump about 10 or 20 seconds each time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MediaPlayer can do much more than play/pause actually. I'm using SoundPool non-stop, so someone should correct me if I'm wrong here.

I think you might need to add different versions of the song (with different speed) and change the actual source each time you want to speed up.